# Quitar el "index.html" con .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo una página web: "http://localhost/my-website.com/".
Pero cuando busco: "http://localhost/my-website.com/index.html", no quiero que se vea el "index.html", si no que solo se muestre "http://localhost/my-website.com/".

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer una redirección con

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://localhost/my-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Pero no es necesario que hagas rutas con los **index**, si tu pones en la url `http://localhost/my-website.com/` no te va a mostrar el index, a no ser que busques específicamente esa ruta `http://localhost/my-website.com/index.html`

Pero con lo del **htacces** que te puse al inicio redireccionas y listo.